# How can you tell if Hangfire task was manually triggered

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, hangfire

I have a Hangfire server set up with several recurring tasks. For local development I don't want these tasks to go through but I need to be able to manually trigger them manually through the Hangfire UI.

I am able to pull the Job Data for the currently running job but I don't see anything within it that tells me if it was manually triggered or not.

Here is an excerpt from my code where RunProcessReportsJob is my RecurringJob in Hangfire

```
public ExitCodeType RunProcessReportsJob(PerformContext context)
        {
                var jobId = context.BackgroundJob.Id;
                var connection = JobStorage.Current.GetConnection();
                var jobData = connection.GetJobData(jobId);

                _logger.LogInformation("Reoccurring job disabled.");
                return ExitCodeType.NoError;
        }
```

The jobData has a ton of information about the job and context but again I don't see anything within this that tells me if it is a manually triggered job or a scheduled job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this helps

```
    private bool JobWasManuallyExecuted(string jobId)
    {
        //'Triggered using recurring job manager' -- Manually triggerd via UI
        //'Triggered by recurring job scheduler' -- using scheduller
        var jobDetails = JobStorage.Current.GetMonitoringApi().JobDetails(jobId);
        if (jobDetails == null)
            return false;

        return jobDetails.History.ToList().Any(x => x.Reason == "Triggered using recurring job manager");
    }
```

This message appears on the UI as well.

Executed using the scheduler:
[image: Executed using the scheduler]

Manually executed
[image: Manually executed]

Comment: Thanks, I knew that message in the UI was the key to tell but I couldn't find it in the code.